# Correct usage of past tenses

Tags: grammar, tenses

When are these sentences most correct and why?

> 1. It was a pretty village and all the houses were restored.
> 2. It was a pretty village and all the houses had been restored.
> 3. It was a pretty village and all the houses have been restored.

Comment: They're all grammatical, but they have slightly different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

2 is easiest to understand.  At some past time, one judges the village to be pretty, and prior to that past time (hence the past perfect) the houses were restored.  The houses' being restored is an explanation for the judgment that the village is pretty.

1 probably means the same, but more is left to the reader to infer, since the time relation between the house restoration and the judgment of prettiness is not made explicit.

3 is a bit obscure, since it is tough to figure out what the two conjoined clauses have to do with one another.